# Generate a .md markdown file from R function

Tags: r, markdown

I am writing an R function that will set up a repository with subdirectories, etc. and would like it to create a template README.md markdown file.

How could an R function generate a README.md file in the current working directory?

Here's a mockup of what I have in mind, but the made-up function `write_md()` is just wishful psuedocode.

```
insert_readme <- function(proj_name){
  write_md(
    paste0(proj_name,
           "\n",
           "===========
Analyst: John Doe \n
Date:", 
           Sys.Date()
           ),
    "README.md")
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you not know how to write to a file? You can use `writeLines` or `cat` or several other options. `writeLines(your_string, "README.md")` will work fine. `your_string` can be a character vector you've built with `paste` or `sprintf` or whatever and by default `writeLines` will put a line break between each element of the vector.

Comment: If you don't want to explicitly add in your own new lines (and can just pass in a vector of lines), look at the `writeLines()` function, otherwise `cat(..., file=)`

Comment: I didn't know how to write a generic text file as opposed to type-specific functions like write.csv. I'd be happy to accept this as an answer.